# How do I kill Brynjolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the quest "Blindsighted" - right after the player and Brynjolf become Nightingales - I had to use cheats to make it work. After that I had Brynjolf following me everywhere.

I've tried killing him, but he just keeps reviving himself, and now he is trying to kill me over and over. I've tried setting him to be mortal but it wont work! How can I kill Brynjolf and be done with this?

Comment: Did you even read the quest requirements?

Answer (score 8):

You can't kill Brynjolf, he is marked as essential throughout the entirety of the game. Also you do not need to kill Brynjolf ever. Also he is supposed to follow you to complete the quest "blindsighted".

The person you kill in "blindsighted" is:

> Mercer Frey

To get rid of Brynjolf, you need to complete the quests so he will stop following you.

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding information (e.g. console commands) about how to pacify Brynjolf, since one of the main issues OP is facing is that Brynjolf is *hostile* to the player.

Answer (score 0):

You can also open the console with the tilde key and click him with your mouse, type disable, and when you want to bring him back type enable.

Comment: Although the OP's idea of the goal of the mission is wrong, this is a viable answer. I wouldn't recommend disabling and enabling NPC's, however; I think it might mess up its scripts.